# Java, OpenCV: How to read/write ORB FeatureDetection parameters

Tags: android, opencv

In OpenCV I am using ORB FeatureDetection in an Android app. It has parameters but these cannot be set directly in Java. The recommended way to set them is to write out a XML or YML file with the params and then read it back in.

However, there seems to be no way to be sure that in fact I have written the file correctly and that the parameters are applied. I thought I could use the write() method to verify that my new settings have taken. But this doesn't seem to work. It does indeed write a proper YML or XML file, but the files have no params.

Here is code to write the files:

```
_detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);

// write initial params. 
String fileName = myDir.getPath() + "/orb_params.yml";
_detector.write(fileName);
fileName = myDir.getPath() + "/orb_params.xml";
_detector.write(fileName);

// try setting some params. 
String tempFileName = writeToFile("tempFile", "%YAML:1.0\nscaleFactor: 1.1\nnLevels: 5\nfirstLevel: 0\nedgeThreshold: 31\npatchSize: 31\n");
_detector.read(tempFileName);

// write params again. 
String fileName = myDir.getPath() + "/orb_params2.yml";
_detector.write(fileName);
fileName = myDir.getPath() + "/orb_params2.xml";
_detector.write(fileName);
```

The xml files look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
</opencv_storage>
```

The yml files look like this:

```
%YAML:1.0
```

Is the write method not implemented in Java? I see that it is implemented in Algorithm.cpp and I assume the ORB Feature Detector just uses that implementation, I see no code to indicate otherwise.

I don't know if this problem is limited to ORB Feature Detection or if other algos suffer these problems when trying to write parameters from Java.

addendum: I see that the write method appears to be implemented in the JNI code: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ddf82d0b154873510802ef75c53e628cd7b2cb13/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp

Answer (score 1):

Got a response on answers.opencv.org and am posting it here for those stumbling across this in the future:

According to [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/76074/send-parameters-to-orb-feature-detector-android/) the read/write function is not implemented in C++ and thus won't work in Android either.